# Python script that takes as input a C written script

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I would like to be able to read a parameter set that is written inside a C code, and build from it a Python dictionary. Is there a smart module in Python/Numpy or else that will start reading a text from a specific 'start' key that I give till another 'end' key?

Comment: What have you done so far? Could you please provide a sample snippet of the input and output you want to have?

Comment: I actually haven't started, I just ask for some direction as I have not encountered yet the need to do it, and I haven't found yet a similar example here in stackoverflow..maybe I will remove this question and come back to it after some more explorations..

Comment: yes itertools.dropwhile or simply iterate over a file object until you hit the start then break when you hit the end